# Ударение в именах Бубнов и Сатин из пьесы Горького "На дне"

Tags: орфоэпия, литература

Возникли сложности с ударениями в именах героев пьесы. Фамилия картёжника Б**у**бнов (от масти карт) или Бубн**о**в (классическое ударение в мужской фамилии)? С**а**тин - настоящая фамилия персонажа (отсылает ли она нас в таком случае к нечистым силам?) или это его кличка Сат**и**н по названию ткани?

Почему так и откуда может быть достоверно известно об ударениях в фамилиях героев пьес?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Б**у**бнов — русская фамилия, ударение обычно ставилось на второй слог. Например: Андре́й Серге́евич Бу́бнов  — советский политический и военный деятель.

**Происхождение фамилии имеет несколько версий**: Фамилия Бубнов образована от прозвища Бубный. Возможно, оно восходит к глаголу «**бубнить**» – «болтать без умолку, разглашать вести». Согласно другой версии, прозвище Бубный ведет свое начало от слова **«бубен**» - ударный музыкальный инструмент, Бубным могли также называть обнищавшего человека. Существовала пословица «Г**ол, как бубен»**. В ярославских говорах это прозвище имело дополнительное значение «лентяй». 
Прозвище Бубный может быть связано и с названием **карточной масти — бубны**.

[Происхождение фамилии Бубнов | ufolog.ru](http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)

2) С**а**тин  - вариантов ударения нет.

**Происхождение фамилии имеет две версии:** а) **Сата, Сатя** — уменьшительные формы от имени Сатир. б) **Сатой** называли в северных губерниях болотное растение или даже само болото. Возможно это перекликается с названием пьесы —Сатин скатился на самое дно — в болото жизни. 
[Значение и происхождение фамилии Сатин | NeoLove.ru](http://names.neolove.ru/last_names/17/sa/satin.html)

Comment: Спасибо. По поводу Сатина - конечно, если это настоящая фамилия, вариант ударения может быть только один. Но если это кличка? Как тот же Барон или Татарин?
Как достоверно узнать, что имел в виду автор. В этом конкретном случае - Горький. Он же мог назвать героя, как ему вздумается без оглядки на общие правила. Была ли "последняя воля" или обсуждение во МХАТе, или не знаю, дневниковая запись?
Как с тем же "Вишнёвым/Вишневым садом". Известно, что для Чехова очень серьёзно стоял этот вопрос. Герой Н.В.Гоголя на самом деле Ноздрёв, а не Ноздрев. Много случаев ошибочного употребление имён героев.

Comment: @Александра, Сатин - это не кличка. Нехарактерно и не обыгрывается в пьесе как кличка. Впрочем, можете послушать в источнике по моей ссылке, там Васька Пепел в середине первого действия к  Сатину обращается, хронометраж сами посмотрите.

Comment: Sibylla, но ведь сатир (ударение на И), сата и сатя (ударение на А и Я), я правильно понимаю? Почему же тогда не Сатин (ударение на И) Где логика?

Comment: @behemothus, не то чтобы я не согласна с Вашим мнением, напротив, но всё-таки, как это так особо обыгрывается кличка? Обращение к Барону ничем не отличается от обращение к Сатину, так же как обращение к Медведеву ничем не отличается от обращения к Актёру. И что вы имеете в виду под нехарактерностью? Нехарактерны клички в целом? Или конкретно это слово не похоже на кличку? О____О

Comment: @Александра А при чем тут Барон? Бароном прозвали самого ничтожного обитателя ночлежки (видимо, до появления в ней), хотя и с прошлым. Тут и обыгрывать ничего не надо. Еще таких оборванцев любили называть Князьями, Царями... Так что Барону еще "повезло". Актер - не совсем кличка в узком смысле, это именно профессия.  Васька Пепел - это тоже понятно, типичное воровское "погоняло". Но с чего бы дать человеку кличку "Сат**и**н"? А если и есть с чего это в пьесе должно быть раскрыто, ружье на стенке должно выстрелить в третьем. В этом смысле - да, нехарактерность.

Comment: Медведев - я чуть было не забыл, кто это))) Ну ну тут и сказать нечего, это реальная фамилия. Да, про Барона. Я думаю, это всё-таки кличка, не реальный его титул.

Comment: @behemothus, понятно, что будь он связан с тканью, это как-нибудь бы проявилось. Для меня очевидно, что Сатин это реальная фамилия, но в разговоре с другим человеком услышала новую версию, мы немного пообсуждали и стало интересно, что по этому поводу думает народ. А потом стало интересно, что Вы подразумеваете под "обыгрыванием" клички. Всё-таки, мне кажется, не всегда клички объясняются по методу ружья, но не буду спорить.

Comment: @behemothus, опять-таки можно серьёзней обсудить характер клички Актёра, но в формате таких комментариев это невероятно неудобно, да и в задачи сайта не входит, как я поняла. Но актёр из Актёра так себе и, судя по всему, обитатели ночлежки прекрасно это понимают. Так что тут изначально его прозвище иронично, насмешливо. Отражение профессии тут как раз-таки вторично и работает только на зрителя/читателя, чтобы он понял прошлое этого героя.

Comment: @behemothus, "тут и сказать нечего, это реальная фамилия... Барон всё-таки кличка, а не реальный титул". 
Про это я и говорю: по общению персонажей между собой нельзя понять, когда используется реальная фамилия, а когда кличка. Ну, то есть к Медведеву вообще обращаются четырьмя способами: Абрам, Абрамка, Абрашка и один раз - Абрам Иванович. Не важно как, если обозначить его как "маску А", а Барона как "маску Б", то они будут взаимозаменяемы. По конструкциям предложений мы не поймём реальное это имя или выдуманное. Не уверена, что понятно объясняю 9_6 Но с Сатиным та же ситуация

Comment: Я имею в виду, вместо "Сатин" можно было бы подставить "Пакля" или "Степан Анатольевич", ничего бы по существу не изменилось. Просто, когда Вы впервые сказали про обыгрывание кличек я подумала именно про такое - синтаксическое обыгрывание, когда маски нельзя будет менять друг с другом... Ну вот, а такого у Горького нет. И понять прозвище перед тобой или фамилия... не то чтобы трудно - в общем плане. А вот если это становится принципиальным вопросом...

Comment: @Александра  *Про это я и говорю: по общению персонажей между собой нельзя понять, когда используется реальная фамилия, а когда кличка*, а я не про это. Хотя спорно. По фамилии там навскидку толка Сатина да  Бубнова и называют. Но Бог с ним, я все равно не об этом.

Comment: Хмм 9_6

Да, только у этих двух героев ничего нет кроме фамилий. Просто не факт, что они настоящие, вот я про что. Если "фамилия" Бубнов (на основе этимологии) появилась именно у этого конкретного человека, а на самом деле он какой-нибудь там... Волков, то его "фамилия" на самом деле - кличка. А "фамилия" Сатина в таком случае может происходить вообще от чего угодно. То есть, традиционно их принято считать настоящими, но на деле эти клички могут ничем не отличаться от того же "Барона" или "Татарина" (хотя у него-то как раз есть своё имя - Асан). Если, в свою очередь, оно верное, исконное...

Answer (score 2):

У Горького - С**а**тин и Б**у**бнов.

Ударения в фамилиях определяется носителем (обычно - по семейной традиции), никакие иные "правила" не могут быть приняты во внимание как аргумент.

С героями пьес - сложнее. Ударение в них определяет автор, но это не всегда соблюдается. Поэтому некоторые авторы (Гоголь, например) даже проставляли ударения в рукописи.

Впрочем, в отношении героев классических пьес, впервые поставленных еще при жизни автора, подобных проблем обычно не возникает. Традиция закрепляется с первой же постановки.

В случае с героями "На дне" правильными считаются ударения С**а**тин (тут просто трудно представить иное) и Б**у**бнов (см. видео http://tvkultura.ru/video/show/brand_id/58203/episode_id/1040988/video_id/1031064/ - примерно 11:38)/

В отношении этимологии. Говорить об этимологии фамилий конкретных героев пьесы не приходится, они выдуманы автором. Причем для Горького использование "говорящих" фамилий (с намеком на происхождение или какое-то качество героя) в целом не характерно, скорее всего это просто случайный, чисто фонетический выбор автора.

Что же касается фамилий вообще, то тут можно более или менее сформулировать этимологию.

Сатин - возможно от дворянского рода Сатиных, этимология туманна, чаше всего возводят к личным именам Сатурн, Сатир, Саторнил, Сатурин и т.п, но недостоверно, эти имена были редкими, а носителей фамилии множество.
http://www.okorneva.ru/proishojdenie--familiy-kamyishlovskogo-uezda-slovar-uralskih-familiy/satin/
Куда вероятнее - от распространённого имени Евстрат, Евстратий. 
И даже что-то тюркское не исключено.

Бубнов - от бубнить или бубен (это родственные слова, я их не разделяю, но второе вернее - с учетом варианта "Бубенцов"), к карточной масти вряд ли имеет отношение, совсем не характерно для русских фамилий. Вариант бубен = нищий не исключаю, но он вторичен.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus, я тоже искренне считала, что второго произношения, кроме как САтин (с ударением на А) быть не может. Но...И приём "говорящих" фамилий для Горького не характерен. В пьесе "На дне" как раз наоборот. если поищу, найду неплохую работу (не помню автора), где достаточно убедительно доказано, что здесь практически все фамилии "говорящие"

Comment: @user183861 Буду признателен за работу. И можно без "уважаемого". На форуме достаточно просто ника, со значком @  впереди. Это получается что-то типа именного тега. Удобно и понятно системе.

Comment: @behemothus , про говорящие фамилии и имена в творчестве Горького Вы ошибаетесь. Опровержения этому найдутся едва ли ни на каждой странице его текстов, про особое отношение автора к имени всем известно. Взять хотя бы банальное "Без имени - нет человека!" и акцентирование на реальной фамилии якобы безымянного Актёра. В пьесе "Последние" главные героини - три сестры Надежда, Вера и Любовь, каждая из которых лишена именно того качества, в честь которого названа. Умирающая покорная Анна носит имя, переводящееся как "благодать", Медведев неуклюж, а Костылёв душевно болен.

Comment: @Александра , Всё это слишком зыбко, но в любом случае из **фамилий** в вашем списке - только Костылев с весьма натянутым объяснением. Никак не аналогия Сатину, будь эта фамилия "говорящая". Говорящими фамилиями "баловались" Салтыков-Щедрин, Чехов, Гоголь, Некрасов (и то у него на прозвища больше смахивает).,А  Медведев еще... Ну вот это еще туда-сюда... Но думаю, что случайное совпадение.

Comment: @behemothus, будет говорящим имя или фамилия уже не суть важно, всё равно один приём =) Поэтому я и объединила их в единое целое.
А Горький во многом был продолжателем Чехова. Но это так... В общем, я совсем не считаю это совпадением и при желании можно было бы развить эту тему серьёзнее и доказательнее, если в этом есть необходимость.
В любом случае, спасибо за Ваши ответы.)

Comment: Но я-то акцентировал именно на Сатине как на якобы "говорящей" фамилии, а это все-таки совсем не то, что Вера, Надежда Любовь. Понимаете, "говорящая" фамилия чем хороша, она намертво пришивается к персонажу. А я того же Медведева и не сразу вспомнил по фамилии. Хотя текст в общем-то знаю (пусть и не любитель Горького).  Знаете, надо подождать Людмилу или Екатерину, они такие вещи лучше чувствуют по профессиональной, так сказать, обязанности.

Answer (score 1):

Из текста пьесы узнаём, что Бубнов ушёл из дома в ночлежку "от греха подальше", после того как жена нашла другого, сам признаётся, что ленив и пьяница. Сатин - шулер, в молодости был телеграфистом. Попал на "дно", после того как четыре года и семь месяцев отсидел в тюрьме за убийство (вступился за честь сестры).

Можно сказать, что в пьесе «сталкиваются» (кроме остальных) и эти два персонажа – философа. Философия Сатина — философия жизни, веселого цинизма, жизнеутверждающего восприятия реальности.  Философия Бубнова — цинизм тяжелый, спокойный, самоуверенный, восприятие жизни как чего-то на веки вечные определившегося, скучного, лишенного красоты и глубокого смысла.

Бубнов (от «бубен» - ударный музыкальный инструмент). От этого возникает и переносное значение: тот, кто постоянно бубнит. Есть еще одно значение - обнищавший, промотавшийся человек (ср. русская пословица: «Гол как бубен»). 
В ярославских говорах - диалектизм: тучный лентяй, тунеядец, прихлебатель.
Фамилия «Сатин» образована от названия мифологического сатира. Сатиры, согласно мифам, -  жизнерадостные существа с ногами, как у козла. Они обладают звериным темпераментом и легко впадают в ярость. 
Эту фамилию также связывают с Сатаной.
С учётом описания образов персонажей, я думаю, ударение ставится на У в фамилии  Бубнов, и на И в фамилии Сатин.